# Cannot overwrite `modelName` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Cannot overwrite `partnerCode` model once compiled.

I have a file like models/partnerCode.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var partnerCodeSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    used: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

var partnerCode = module.exports = mongoose.model('partnerCode', partnerCodeSchema);

module.exports.add = function(code){
    partnerCode.findOne({email:code},function(err,response){
        console.log(response);
    }); 
}
```

and in my app.js I try to add an end point to make rest POST

```
var PartnerCodeModel = require('./models/PartnerCode');
app.post('/PartnerCodeModel/add', PartnerCodeModel.add( function(req,res,next){
  console.log('code: '+req.body.code);
}))
```

Above code won't work, I got `Cannot overwrite partnerCode model once compiled` why ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var partnerCodeSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    used: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

var partnerCode = mongoose.model('partnerCode', partnerCodeSchema);

module.exports.add = function(code){
    partnerCode.findOne({email:code},function(err,response){
        console.log(response);
    }); 
}
```

If you need any further assistance then comment on this answer. I would like to help you. :-)

Comment: can u clarify my mistake please?